# Forcing to WIC to treat image data as RGB

Tags: c++, image-processing, wic

I have a image as a BYTE array(in RGB format) and I needed to encode it. I did, but colors have changed.

```
/*Create stream and initialized*/
hr = piFactory->CreateStream(&piStream);
hr = piStream->InitializeFromFilename(L"..\\test.jpg",GENERIC_WRITE);

/*created an encoder. I want to save JPG*/
hr = piFactory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, NULL, &piEncoder);
```

did some manipulations, also tried to set pixel format.

```
hr = piBitmapFrame->SetPixelFormat(&formatGUID);
```

but it always set to "GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR"

and i write image data as here.

```
/*pBitmap contains image data*/
hr = piBitmapFrame->WritePixels(lHeight, cbStride, cbBufferSize, pBitmap);
```

the problem was colors of the image has changed, and I found that if i change RGB to BGR then the output looks fine. so i did this

```
   for(int i = 0; i < DataSize; i += 3)
    {
        inBuff[i] = pBitmap[i+2];
        inBuff[i + 1] = pBitmap[i+1];
        inBuff[i + 2] = pBitmap[i];
    }

    pBitmap = inBuff
```

But i dont want to expend more time here looping through whole image. 
I need to tell WIC "treat the data as RGB(or BGR)".

is that possible? if it is then how?

Comment: I would like to link this answers too in SU.http://superuser.com/questions/904978/does-the-jpeg-file-format-support-rgb-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bitmap first. at that time you could say the format it needs to be. Here is "24bppRGB" format:

```
    hr = piFactory->CreateBitmapFromMemory(
        lWidth,
        lHeight,
        GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppRGB,
        cbStride,
        cbBufferSize,
        pBitmap,
        &piBitmapSrc
        );
```

This is how You write image data into the frame:

```
hr = piBitmapFrame->WritePixels(lHeight, cbStride, cbBufferSize, pBitmap);
```

Instead write image to the frame like this (because `WritePixels()` doesn't accept bitmap):

```
    hr = piBitmapFrame->WriteSource(
        piBitmapSrc,
        NULL
        );
```

And that help to avoid the loop. I'm not sure what happens inside the `CreateBitmapFromMemory()` though. Since you are concerned with time, I don't know if this will help (it still makes your code better).

Comment: Looks Like its working. since the input of WIC is a RGB bitmap no more automatic color changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way.
[This forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4e0a03b1-67db-4c36-949b-c49ec5a212d5/wic-treat-input-data-as-bgr?forum=windowswic&prof=required) says,

This is covered on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797.aspx#jpeg__native_codec)

The JPEG encoder encodes three formats:

- GUID_WICPixelFormat8bppGray
- GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR
- GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppCMYK

If your source data is in a different format, you need to use IWICFormatConverter as part of your chain.